# Ionic-selectable with error on multiple selection within a form

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: I'm making a simple Ionic Selectable component for a user to be able to select a value and submit it. On submission the value should be saved in Firebase database under a unique id (date and time stamp generated). I've got it working using a text value, however, on using Ionic selectable I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on
>   non-object at e.set [as value]

There's a lot of code involved in this including the Firebase codes, but since that appears to be working I'm just posting my relevant codes. Please let me know if any additional information is needed to get around this error.

It actually works if I don't add the option of [isMultiple] within the form, however, when I add that, I get that error.

Here's my home.html file:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Ionic Selectable</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
    <form [formGroup]="form" margin-bottom>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Diagnosis</ion-label>
      <ionic-selectable
        item-content
        formControlName="diagnosis"
        [items]="diagnoses"
        [isMultiple]="true"
        [canSearch]="true"
        (onChange)="diagnosisChange($event)">
      </ionic-selectable>
    </ion-item>
              <div margin-top padding>
                  <button margin-top round ion-button block [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
              </div>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

My home.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicSelectableComponent } from 'ionic-selectable';
import { IonicPage, NavController, ViewController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { DiagnosisService } from '../../services';
import { Diagnosis } from '../../types';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  diagnoses: Diagnosis[];
  diagnosisControl: FormControl;
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private view: ViewController,
    private diagnosisService: DiagnosisService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.diagnoses = this.diagnosisService.getDiagnoses();
    this.diagnosisControl = this.formBuilder.control(this.diagnoses[0],
      Validators.required);
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      diagnosis: this.diagnosisControl
    });
  }

    diagnosisChange(event: {
    component: IonicSelectableComponent,
    value: any
  }) {
    console.log('diagnosis:', event.value);
  }

submit() {
        this.close();
    }

close() {
        this.view.dismiss();
    }
}
```

My diagnosis.service.ts file is as below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Diagnosis } from '../types';

@Injectable()
export class DiagnosisService {
  private diagnoses: Diagnosis[] =
    ['Hypothyroidism', 'Hyperthyroidism', 'Diabetes Type 1', 'Diabetes Type 2'];

  getDiagnoses(page?: number, size?: number): Diagnosis[] {
    let diagnoses = [];

      this.diagnoses.forEach(diagnosis => {
        diagnoses.push(diagnosis);
      });

    if (page && size) {
      diagnoses = diagnoses.slice((page - 1) * size, ((page - 1) * size) + size);
    }

    return diagnoses;
  }

  getDiagnosesAsync(page?: number, size?: number, timeout = 2000): Observable<Diagnosis[]> {
    return new Observable<Diagnosis[]>(observer => {
      observer.next(this.getDiagnoses(page, size));
      observer.complete();
    }).pipe(delay(timeout));
  }
}
```

I've managed to create [a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-selectable-form-control-7dkjrq) that recreates my issue as well. You can see that, as soon as I remove `[isMultiple]="true"`, it works. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So I've been using this plugin and It works very well and the documentation has a lot of info on issues. One thing I noticed on your stack blitz code is in your Types directory with diagnosis.ts you dont have the element names assigned to your array. The benefit of this is to explicitly entail your values even if it's one value. You can use the ID of the values and name of your values. for example:

```js
export class Diagnosis {
    public id: number;
    public name: string;
}
```

Also, I noticed on your html and ts files you seem to be using either asynchronous searching or virtual scroll but you're missing some code on your `diagnosisChange()` function to filter the data with your service according to the docs. I would make sure you follow the [Examples](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-selectable-on-search?file=services%2Fport.service.ts). One thing I would recommend is to make sure the functionality on your ionic selectable works correctly before storing to firebase. Of course the selectable element will store as a key-value pair to your form, so make sure that is coming in correctly when the form is submitted.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sure, if I include public name: string; in the types directory and change my array to include a 'name: ' prior to the items there, it does work, however, how would I define the export for my current array that does not include a 'name: ' prior to the string? I tried just using 'string;' and that still gave a console error. Any ideas? The array is something I'm calling from another database and isn't modifiable.

Comment: So just to clarify you’re getting an error on the ionic searchable and not the form submission correct? Also you can manipulate the array to change into an object array and then convert back to just a value when you submit to your api. I had to do that with an array from my api and it worked fine. I know it’s a little more trouble on the front-end, but unfortunately that’s the downside with using plugins or imports. They’re normally already pre-defined so it’s hard to manipulate the code for that end.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. True, that's a round-about way of doing things, but should work as you said. I thought there might just be some easier way and was doing something wrong while using the plugin. If that's the way to go about it, will go ahead and do that then, thanks!

Comment: I’m sure there is definitely an easier way of converting the data . Back-end is always the easiest, but of course it’s your preference. If you update your question with the exact parameters I can try to update my sender that will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I spoke too soon. I didn't have formControl defined. It actually doesn't work even with when defining the types. I actually checked the developer's own stackblitz demo (https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-selectable-form-control) and it looks like it doesn't work either when you add [isMultiple]="true" within the form. It looks like it is a plugin limitation (doesn't work within forms) and needs to be addressed with the author.